# Delete CA certificate but it is automatically restored - need to permanently delete it

Tags: windows-server-2016, ca, godaddy-api

A infrastructure scan indicates we must delete a specific CA Certificate.

*The following known CA certificates were part of the certificate
chain sent by the remote host, but contain hashes that are considered
to be weak.*

*Subject             : C=US/O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc./OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
Signature Algorithm : SHA-1 With RSA Encryption*

Now I delete the specific certificate but it reappears/is restored the very next day - perhaps even sooner. Note that I don't want to remove GoDaddy as a CA, but just delete this one SHA-1 CA certificate.

What could I do to remove this certificate permanently?

[image]

Comment: If you want to not trust it, your best bet is to copy it into the Disallowed store.  But I'll leave this as a comment in case someone knows how to stop Windows from recovering specific certs from Windows Update; which would be the real answer.